# Sections Framework Materialize

Tags: material-design, materialize

In some frameworks we can develop throughout the app in single page .

I drew my app using appframework.js Intel and want to migrate it to materialize , but researched enough in his documentation and have not found a way to make a layout with several pages but in a single html file.

Just I saw ways to do this by invoking other external html files , creating other pages .

Does anyone know to do that? Can pass me a layout or indicate where can I find this information?

It offers a well Layout Material Design as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AngularJS to inject pages into your main template. This does not cause the page to load again.

You can read more here:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating